# Убрать текст из блока

Tags: javascript

Есть такой скрипт:

```
 var wpcomment = document.getElementById('post_new_txt');
 wpcomment.onkeyup = wpcomment.onkeypress = function(){
     document.getElementById('flash').innerHTML = ('Пишет вам сообщение');
 }
```

При вводе текста показывает "Пишет вам сообщение", а если удалить все, то все равно показывает. Нужно скрыть эту надпись если человек не пишет. Как это реализовать?

Comment: тут нет jquery. возвращайтесь из обработчика события и присваивайте в innerHTML элемента flash пустую строку, если `this.value===''`

Comment: @eicto Спасибо вам большое.

Answer (score 1):

ответ из комментария:

возвращайтесь из обработчика события и присваивайте в `innerHTML` элемента `flash` пустую строку, если `this.value===''`.

Answer (score 0):

Добавте к вашему коду проверку на `keyup`:

```
wpcomment.onkeyup = function() {
    document.getElementById("flash").innerHTML = "";
}
```

Таким образом при событии `keyup` мы очищаем `document.getElementById("flash")`. Всё очень просто.